# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error and also Message larger than modulus

Tags: java, encryption

Below I try to send message in multicast socket through group and to provide encryption:

1. Encrypt the data with the symmetric key
2. Encrypt the symmetric key with rsa
3. send the encrypted key and the data
4. Decrypt the encrypted symmetric key with rsa
5. decrypt the data with the symmetric key

But I am getting this error

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error  at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:378)  at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:290)     at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:366)  at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:392)    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2208)  at Security.RSADecryption(Symmetra.java:63)     at ReadThread.run(Symmetra.java:202)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

I think I did not understood encryption decryption properly.

See below for the code:

```
class Security
{
    public static SecretKey createAESKey() throws Exception
    {
        KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        generator.init(128); // The AES key size in number of bits
        SecretKey key = generator.generateKey();
        return key;
    }

    public static KeyPair generateRSAkeyPair() throws Exception
    {
        //SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    
        //KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(4096);
    
        KeyPair pair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        return pair;
    }

    public static byte[] AESEncryption(String plaintext, SecretKey secKey) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secKey);
    
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes());
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static byte[] RSAEncryption(PublicKey publicKey, SecretKey key) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    
        //cipher.update(plaintext.getBytes());
        byte [] encryptedKey = cipher.doFinal(key.getEncoded());
        System.out.println(encryptedKey.length);
        return encryptedKey;
    }

    public static byte[] RSADecryption(byte[] encryptedKey, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte check[] = cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);
        
        return cipher.doFinal(encryptedKey);
    }

    public static String AESDecryption(byte[] decryptedKey, byte[] text) throws Exception
    {
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decryptedKey , 0, decryptedKey.length, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey);
        byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(text);
        return new String(plaintext);
    }

    public static KeyPair generate() throws Exception
    {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRSAkeyPair();
        return keyPair;
    }
}

public class TestDemo extends Security
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        KeyPair keyPair = generate();
        SecretKey key = createAESKey();

        byte[] cipherText = AESEncryption(message,key);
        byte[] encryptedKey = RSAEncryption(keyPair.getPublic(), key);
  
        DatagramPacket datagram = new
        DatagramPacket(cipherText,cipherText.length,group,port);  // It carries encrpyted message

        // It carries symmetric key encrypted by RSA
        DatagramPacket datagram2 = new
        DatagramPacket(encryptedKey,encryptedKey.length,group,port); 
        socket.send(datagram);
        socket.send(datagram2);
    }
}

class ReadThread extends Security
{
    KeyPair keyPair;
    SecretKey key;
    try
    {
        keyPair = generate();
        key = createAESKey();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ReadThread.MAX_LEN]; 
        DatagramPacket datagram = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,group,port);
        
        byte[] keyBuffer = new byte[512]; 
        DatagramPacket datagram2 = new
        DatagramPacket(keyBuffer,keyBuffer.length,group,port);
                
                
        String message;
                
        try
        { 
            socket.receive(datagram);
            socket.receive(datagram2);
            byte[] decryptKey = RSADecryption(keyBuffer,keyPair.getPrivate());
            String decryptText = AESDecryption(decryptKey, buffer);
                    
            message = decryptText;
            if(!message.startsWith(Symmetra.name)) 
                System.out.println(message); 
        } 
        catch(IOException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Socket closed!"); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend to leave out the complete "Datagram-part" and stay on pure encryption and decryption. Secondly you should debug the data to find out at which place differences occur.

Comment: Thirdly: On decryption side you generate the RSA + symmetric key again - you have to use the RSA private key from encryption side to decrypt the data. The symmetric/AES key does not need to get generated as it should be decrypted by the RSA decryption.

Comment: BTW: usually the RSA key pair is generated by the RECEIVER of the message, then the public key is provided to the SENDER that does the encryption. Kindly overthink your complete project, thanks.

Comment: Agree, you first need to distribute the key from the receiver(s) and make sure you can trust it at the sender's site before being able to perform encryption with it. If you have multiple receivers you can encrypt the AES key multiple times (or you'd use different form of multi-party key establishment).

Comment: @MichaelFehr I can not remove Datagram part since without it I can not send messages. I removed generating of RSA key again on decryption side but still problem persists. Please kindly help me out

Comment: @MaartenBodewes How can I send key from receiver side? I am not able to understand that